# Read Environment Variable From Azure App Service

Tags: azure, environment-variables

I'm using ocelot for API gateway.
We are deploying our app to azure.
I want to read ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT from azure app settings.
On azure, it has Production and Stage values for 2 apps.
But after deployment, I'm always having Development value which is a local one.
I cannot make it happen to read the value from Azure.
I have put the key and value on Configuration=>Application Settings but it didn't work.
What is missing?

[azure config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrodq.png)

This is how I read the value

```
var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
```

In application settings, there is also defined.

[api appsettings value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZEaS.png)

It is Development in launchSettings.json
[launchsettings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18a4A.png)

I have spent hours and couldn't figure it out.
They all say just call it like that,
So why I can't read the value from Azure then?

Comment: local settings file overwrite App Settings configuration. You should match the values or remove from one of them

Comment: Ohh, I didn't expect it was that easy. I just changed the variable name and it worked. I supposed azure settings will override. Thx.